# Does my app need SSL on its Paypal redirection & landing pages?

Tags: security, web-applications, ssl, paypal

I want to add Paypal functionality to my app but I'm kind of in the dark about some of the security issues.

Specifically, when the user wants to pay, I have to redirect them to Paypal and then Paypal sends me some kind of token/key to indicate whether the payment took place.

So, on the page where I pass the user to Paypal, do I need SSL? Why/why not?

What about the page where I receive the response token from Paypal?

Is it possible for a hacker, for example, to make up some random token and post it to my app to pretend that he paid?

If so, does this mean I need to make another call to Paypal after I receive the token - to make sure the token is real?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before using drupal e-commerce to sell app downloads via Paypal and used SSL neither on the redirection nor the landing page. While technically I suppose a hacker could intercept the token of someone who paid for the app and use it to pretend he paid, I don't think this is likely scenario because the average criminal is more interested in credit card numbers than one-time free access to some product/service. Further, one of the main reasons you would use Paypal in the first place is so that you wouldn't have to pay as much attention to security as you would if you had to process the users credit cards yourself since Paypal takes care of this for you (and their system is secured by SSL).

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I'm wrong but I think that without ssl the following two scenarios are possible using a man-in-the-middle attack:

**phishing:**
the hacker redirects the user to a paypal-like site and receives his paypal user/pw or credit card details.
this attack isn't perfect as phishing sites do get found and pulled down.

**hijacking the payment:**
the hacker creates his own real paypal token (order data scrapped from your site) but with his own paypal account as the receiver and redirect the customer to that address. in this case paypal's policies might be enough to make this actions pointless.